# Can not access __reactInternalInstance$ on HTML Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm creating a Chrome extension and I need to get React instance from HTML Element. While I was playing with the website and testing this function to get React instance from HTML Element all worked as I expected.

```js
function getReactInstance(element: HTMLElement | undefined): Record<string, any> | undefined {
    if (element === undefined) {
       return;
    }

    for (const key in element) {
        if (key.startsWith('__reactInternalInstance$')) {
            return (element as any)[key] as any;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to call the same function with the same HTML Element it returned `undefined`.

I did a little bit more debugging and found that if I try to call `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` on the HTML Element I got 2 different results.

Called from Chrome extension script:

```js
[]
```

Called from Developer Console on the website:

```js
['__reactInternalInstance$n8lnk6b117', '__reactEventHandlers$n8lnk6b117']
```

My question is: How can I access all properties on an object from the Chrome extension content script?

Answer (score 0):

After some scavenging on the Internet and I have created a blurry picture of what could be the underlying issue. My assumption was correct. The problem was that Chrome extension's content scripts run in ISOLATED worlds. Changing `manifest.json` to include `world` set to `"MAIN"` fixed all of my issues.

```json
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
      ...
      "world": "MAIN"
  }]
}
```